# how to refer to a non-declared variables in setResultConverter

Tags: javafx, dialog, dynamic-variables

I'd like to re-use a dialog class for data manipulation.  The data will be retrieved from database.  It depends on which table the class retrieve the data from, the size of the table columns is not fixed, so I can't declare column variables.  After users update data, I would like to convert the input data using setResultConverter but do not know how to refer to the variable, since the program generates TextFields dynamically.  Please help.  Here is the the code.

```
public class AddDialog {
   private Dialog<DBtable> dialog = new Dialog<DBtable>();
   private ButtonType saveBtn;
   //database variables
  private Connection connect; // = null;
  private String dbTblName;
   //gridpane content variables
  private GridPane contentPane = new GridPane();
  private HashMap<String, TextField> fieldMap = 
                 new HashMap<String, TextField>();
  private ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();

   public AddDialog (String title, String header, String dbTable) {
       this.dbTblName = dbTable;

       dialog.setTitle(title);
       dialog.setHeaderText(header);

       saveBtn = new ButtonType("Save", ButtonData.OK_DONE);
       dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(saveBtn, 
                                          ButtonType.CANCEL);

       dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(getLayout(dbTable));

      Optional<DBtable> result = dialog.showAndWait();

      result.ifPresent(data -> {
               System.out.println(" data="+data+" 0="+data.getID()+
        " 1="+data.getField1());
        });

 } // constructor ends

public GridPane getLayout(String dbTable) {
String  sql =   "select column_name, description ";
    sql +=  "from   syscolumn_description ";
    sql +=  "where  table_name = \'" + dbTable + "\'";
String fieldLabel, fieldCol;
ResultSet ds = null;
// retrieve meta data from database

connect  = DBConnect.getConnect(connect);
try {
   Statement labelStmnt = connect.createStatement();
   ds = labelStmnt.executeQuery(sql);

   int row = 0;
   while (ds.next()) {
    row += 2;
    //label....column=0 row=row+2;
    fieldLabel = ds.getString("DESCRIPTION");
    contentPane.add(new Text(fieldLabel), 0, row);

    //textField...column=1 row=row+2;
    contentPane.add(new TextField(), 1, row);
    fieldCol = ds.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
    fieldMap.put(fieldCol, new TextField());

   } // while result set loop ends
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
   try {if(ds != null) ds.close();} catch (Exception e) {};
}

    // convert result
dialog.setResultConverter(dialogButton -> {
    if (dialogButton == saveBtn) {
       int i=0;
       for (Map.Entry<String, TextField> e : fieldMap.entrySet()) {
        dataList.add(e.getValue().getText());
        i++;
        System.out.println("col="+e.getKey()+
            " data="+e.getValue().getText());
       } // map loop end

       return new DBtable(dataList, i);
    }
    return null;
});

return contentPane;

} //getLayout ends
} // AddDialog ends
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense to me. Can you please re-write your question describing what exactly is the issue and where is the blocker?

Comment: I would like a dialog popup when users want to create/edit a database table entry. I cannot declare database table columns in the dialog since I do not know how many of them there will be.  It all depends on which database table user wants to do data manipulation.  If I don't have table columns name then how can I convert the result- setResultConverter users entered and then insert/update the database table?

Comment: This is how I create a TextField: contentPane.add(new TextField(), 1, row); instead of : contentPane.add(aTextField, 1, row);

Comment: This is how I create a TextField: contentPane.add(new TextField(), 1, row); instead of : contentPane.add(aTextField, 1, row);  when dialog.setResultConvert....if I had "TextField aTextField =  new TextField()" then I can "return new dataStructure(aTextField.getText();" but since I do not have variable aTextField declared then I don't how to convert the result.